# Swift 4 - How to get bounds of a UIView after Using Constraints Programatically

Tags: swift, autolayout, constraints, bounds

I really need your help about this issue. I am creating a UIView object programatically without setting the bounds at the beggining. After creating I add constraints to that view in order to fit the required place in the screen.

But the problem is that, I want to use that UIView's bounds property in the following parts of the code but unfortunately I can not get the bounds after constraints sets as it shows on the screen.

Below I have sample code :

```
     let previewView = UIView()

     NSLayoutConstraint(item: previewView, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: upperView, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0).isActive = true

     NSLayoutConstraint(item: previewView, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0).isActive = true


    previewView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: self.view.frame.width).isActive = true

    previewView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false


    print(previewView.bounds)
   // (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0) ->>>> How can I get the bounds as it shows on the screen instead of 0,0,0,0
```

---

After this point, when I try to use, previewView.bounds property, it returns me its original size as 0.

How can I get the bounds as it shows on the screen with the related constaints' setup ?

Thank you very much Guys.

Comment: Just print bounds after call `preview.superview.layoutIfNeeded()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can access it in

```
 override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    if once { 
        once = false
        // process here
        print(previewView.bounds) 
    } 
 }
```

but first declare the view as instance variable , make `once = false` in view

```
var previewView:UIView! 
var once= true
```

see here[image]

Comment: Hi My Friend,  When I try your advice, I can get exactly what I need. But this means that I should move my code from viewDidLoad to viewDidLayoutSubviews() . Do you think this make sense ?

Comment: You are correct. I tried the same thing on my Mac also :) But I can not decide if it is a good approach to move the codes to the viewDidLayoutSubviews. What do you advice ?

Comment: you can do this but wrap all the code in Once bool variable as this method is being called multiple times

Comment: Aha, you mean I should check if it is the first time before executing the code ?